# Android intent filter (android:host) with regexp

Tags: android, intentfilter

Is it possible to have regular expression (regexp) on intent filter to filter various host addresses? I tried to write, but failed, so looking for some help.

I have lot of domains and want to write intent filter to match all these examples:

1. http://example.com/
2. http://example.ru/
3. http://example.org/
4. http://example.biz/

and more from the previous version that is still supported.

5. http://previousversion.com/
6. http://previousversion.ru/

...

also there could be http and https; with and without www.

Below code example is working, but if i want to write all conditions it would take a lot of space in manifest, so I'm looking for a better way. Main point that path prefix is the same, but host and scheme is changing.

```
<data
     android:host="www.example.com"
     android:pathPrefix="/operation/accept/"
     android:scheme="https"/>

<data
     android:host="example.com"
     android:pathPrefix="/operation/accept/"
     android:scheme="https"/>

<data
     android:host="www.example.com"
     android:pathPrefix="/operation/accept/"
     android:scheme="http"/>

<data
     android:host="example.com"
     android:pathPrefix="/operation/accept/"
     android:scheme="http"/>
...
```

Comment: I have tried to do the same, but IIRC it seems that wildcards are not accepted in the host part of the scheme.

Comment: maybe it can't be done in better way :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no regex supported in `android:host`, it only supports asterisk wildcard, you could check this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.

But, I found another way to write path only once, like below. (reference: https://riptutorial.com/android/example/12833/multiple-domains-and-multiple-paths)

```xml
<data android:scheme="https"
        android:host="*.example.com" />

<data android:scheme="https"
        android:host="*.example2.com" />

<data android:path="/operation/accept/" />
```

It'll produce following links.

- https://*.example.com/operation/accept/
- https://*.example2.com/operation/accept/

Answer (score -1):

There is no regex support. You can use pathPattern which only allows you to use .* and * wildcards in path segments. For the host you can use * as first character only.

Comment: Just a small correction. android:host supports a '*' wildcard as the initial character. The host part of the authority to match. May start with a single '*' to wildcard the front of the host name.

Comment: @luciofm what do you mean the android:host supports a wildcard?  The " character kind of threw off the formatting.  Does this mean you can use a wildcard to accept any host?

Comment: @themichaelscott yep, you can use `android:host="*"` or `android:host="*.something.com"`

Comment: @luciofm answer should be the accepted one, I confirmed "\*" works as a wildcard, even though ".\*" didn't seem to work for some reason :/